# Validation check for text field in extjs4 as of following format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, extjs4

I need the text filed validation in the format of starts with "Cell" followed by single white space followed by # followed by white space and followed by 1 or more number i.e., "Cell # 1234". i need separate function to evaluate this thing. can anyone help me

here is the code

```
this.mcmMobileIdentifierTextbox = new Ext.form.TextField({
            fieldLabel: 'Cell#',
            id: 'MobileIdentifier',
            x: 280,
            y: 10,
            width: 200,
            labelWidth: 70,
            regex:  /(Cell \s\#\S/d+/),
            listeners: {
                scope: this,
                specialkey: function(f, e) {
                    if(e.getKey() === e.ESC) {
                        this.hide();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Please help me Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on separate function for validation, you can create function

```
function(value) {

    var patt = /^Cell\s#\s\d+$/;

    return patt.test(value);        
}
```

Then you can use this function as validator for textfield. In textfield configuration you can provide validator function in [`validator`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-validator) configuration property.

See live example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/28a

Comment: pls help me for this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087958/timefield-combobox-issue-in-grid-using-extjs4